Go, Error Handling, and Big Text Files - express error semantics in types
The title Go, Error Handling, and Big Text Files is a blog post from Wesley Aptekar-Cassels from 2021. In this blog post he reports about a problem he faced parsing long text files. He tried
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

but was surprised that the parsing did return nothing. He writes

What's going on here? Well, it turns out that when a line is longer
than bufio.MaxScanTokenSize, which defaults to 65536, the scanner will
silently stop scanning. I guess you're supposed to know that:
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

Is the invocation that you're supposed to use, but the compiler won't warn you, go vet won't warn you, staticcheck won't warn you.

In the last paraph he wrote

Update: Someone asked me about the feasibility of writing a static
check to catch this error. It seem to me that it should be quite easy,
given the static analysis infrastructure that exists already for Go,
but th problem is that this kind of API (which Go seems to have a lot
of) doesn't express the error semantics in the types, but rather
leaves it implicit in the structure of the library code — this means
that a static check for this can't be generic, but instead has to
specifically know about the error semantics of bufio.Scanner, which
are only expressed in the docs. It's easy to make a static check for
this exact thing, but it's essentially impossible to write a static
check that will catch this entire category of error.

Can someone eli5 (explain like i am 5) the bit but it's essentially impossible to write a static check that will catch this entire category of error. Why the type system is not well suited to handle this type of errors in a generc way?

It's not the type system that is to blame but the library authors who chose to implement functions such that errors are not communicated through types:

[the] problem is that this kind of API (which Go seems to have a lot
of) doesn't express the error semantics in the types, but rather
leaves it implicit in the structure of the library code

If they had used types (I'm not familiar with Go, but Rust for example has a Result<> type) it would be easy to statically check whether the caller of a function that returns such a type handles it or ignores it. In fact, that's what the cargo check and the VS Code language servers do. But statically checking whether each caller of a library function handles its error conditions appropriately is much harder as it needs to be implemented for each one, possibly differently for each.

I don't think this is about Rust Result va Go error, but about accumulating errors inside an object, and having to retrieve it via a custom method. This approach isn't entirely insane – a similar FP pattern is known as "railway-oriented programming" – but it relies on manually checking the error at the end. No mainstream language – not even Rust – has type system features like linear types to enforce this check. But safer designs would panic if an object is destroyed with unconsumed errors, or use a callback-based withScanner(f) design to automatically extract errs at the end.
